# String operation in Python. Parse URL

Tags: python

```
print full_url = request.get_host()+request.get_full_path()
```

Result:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/test/en/

or

> 127.0.0.1:8000/test/ru/

How to check if the end of the string is `/en/` or `/ru/`

Comment: You can use find function of string to verify the string ends with '/en/' or '/ru/' Such as url = '127.0.0.1:8000/test/ru/' url.find('/ru/')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `endswith`:

```
full_url.endswith('/en/') or full_url.endswith('/ru/')
```

If you find that there are more extensions you have to cover, you may consider using `any`:

```
any(s.endswith(ext) for ext in ['/ru/', '/en/'])
```

Comment: Thanks, what if `ru` is not on the end of the string `127.0.0.1:8000/ru/test/`?

Comment: Then u can use find function full_url.find('ru')

Comment: @Raman: In that case you would use `in`, e.g. `'/en/' in full_url or '/ru/' in full_url`.

Comment: You don't need to use `any` or `or` here: `.endswith` accepts a tuple.  For example: `full_url.endswith(('/en/','/ru/'))`.

Comment: @DSM: Ah, that's pretty cool, I didn't know that! You should make it an answer so that I could upvote it, I think that's a much nicer solution than what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the four final characters:

```
full_url[-4:]
```

or use the `ends_with` string method:

```
if full_url.ends_with("/en/"):
  print 'en'
elif full_url.ends_with("/ru/"):
  print 'ru'
```